# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio concatenating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been working on this for about 2 days, and I can not for the life of me understand what I am doing wrong. Basically, I am trying to take a temporary table that I have made (which I have already combined the columns for). Now I am trying to combine the rows, and after 20 solid hours of searching I can not find the solution. I'm hoping someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

```
DECLARE @ThisUID int;
DECLARE @ThisUIDName varchar;

SELECT TOP 1 @ThisUIDName = ElementName 
FROM ElementNames 
WHERE ElementUID = @ThisUID

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT v.ElementUID, 
    '^'+a.ElementAttribute + '|' + Value1 + Value2 as Combined 
    FROM ElementAttributeValues v 
    Left JOIN ElementAttributes a 
    ON v.ElementAttribute = a.UID 
)
SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable 
FROM CTE 

SELECT 
    a.ElementUID, a.Combined
    STUFF((SELECT CAST( '' as varchar(max)) + e.Combined
           FROM #TempTable
           WHERE e.ElementUID = a.ElementUID
           FOR xml path(''), type). as a.Combined
FROM #TempTable a
ORDER BY a.ElementUID DESC
```

If any can explain what is doing horribly wrong for me I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Also: I assume you meant SQL Server Management Studio (often referred to as **SSMS**) and not really **MSDN** as you had put in your title. I've taken the liberty to change that for you

Comment: How does this even run? You are missing the last 3 arguments to STUFF and a right paren.  Something is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see a comma (,) after the first line in your final SELECT statement (after a.Combined), and secondly, I think it's really bad idea to also call the value of the STUFF statement the same - .. as a.Combined - try to use distinct names

So try this as your final `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
    a.ElementUID, a.Combined,   -- add a comma at the end of this line
    STUFF((SELECT CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + e.Combined
           FROM #TempTable
           WHERE e.ElementUID = a.ElementUID
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS Stuffed     -- use a distinct name here!
FROM #TempTable a
ORDER BY a.ElementUID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are not passing the exact number of arguments to your stuff function. stuff accepts 4 arguments.
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )

even as marc mentioned comma is missed, extra . after type) is there